# The most common element in 2d array.How to optimize?

Tags: java, optimization, multidimensional-array

I have this task, find the most commonly seen element in int[][] array and print the number and times repeated.I solved the problem.

A friend of mine said that having 4 `for()`s is a bad idea.So I decided to try optimising it to remove one or two, but couldn't figure a way.

So here it is:

```
     int cnt, element = arr[0][0], numberRepeats = 0;//cnt-counter,what's the element ,how many times it's repeated
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {//those two for's are for the current element
            cnt = 0;//counter is nullified
            for (int j2 = i; j2 < arr.length; j2++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < arr[j2].length; k++) {//and those two are the compared element
                    if (arr[i][j] == arr[j2][k]) {//if the current element is the same as the compared element,increase counter
                        cnt++;
                    }
                }

            if (cnt > numberRepeats) {//after the compared element is done comparing and the number of repeats of the current element is more then the lastly checked element
                element = arr[i][j];//we get the element ,and how many times it's repeated
                numberRepeats = cnt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only optimisation that I could think of was starting the counting from the current element till the end.

Please give me some more ideas. All the answers I could find were for the 1D array, and they were all pretty much the same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just iterate your whole array and count the occurrences of every element in a map.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> elementsCounts = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        Integer count = elementsCounts.get(arr[i][j]])
        if(count == null){
          count = 0
        }
        elementsCounts.put(arr[i][j]], count+1)
    }
}
```

Now all it gets is to find the key with the maximum value in the map.

Comment: So,all I need to do is learn what the hell a Map is : )
THANK YOU :)

Comment: @KostadinKostadinov [Map tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

Answer (score 0):

We need to use Map and as well as Set (Set to identify the duplicate elements in a row), only using Map will overlook an edge case scenario where duplicate value in a row may result in incrementing the counter. And finally will be considered as a common value.

Summarizing in below steps:

1. Populate map with key as a the value of array [i][j] and Map's value as a counter.
2. IF element is absent in the Map then add key-value pair, Mpa's value as counter initializing from 1.
3. ELSE, update the element in the Map incrementing the counter with 1
4. Before incrementing the counter check for duplicate value in the row using Set
5. Finally, iterate the Map using entrySet() and print only those element whose counter is equal to length of array.

input e.g.:

```
Integer [][] array = {{1,2,3},{1,4,5,5},{1,5,7}};
```

output result:

```
{1}
```